# Matching a pattern of file name after wildcard

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a couple of files, `XR3_DEV_YEAR20_Z.7_ROP_Current*.csv` and
`XR3_DEV_YEAR20_Z.7_ROP_Previous*.csv`

I'm trying to take the pattern of these file names and get the bit after the wildcard so it matches this: 
`XR3_DEV_YEAR20_Z.7_ROP_*_xml.txt`

I'm trying to do this with the `re` or `glob` library, but I'm not really sure how to do it.

Comment: Check out the [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Comment: Oh actually, I might have misunderstood the problem. Could you clarify what you're trying to do exactly? For example if you want to match filenames using Unix-style wildcards (not regex), you can actually use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html).

Comment: Actually, glob might be easier

Comment: Are you trying to create names for an XML file, so they correspond to the name of a given CSV file?

Comment: yes, but they need the _xml.txt at the end of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a way to do that:

```
exp = re.compile(r"^XR3_DEV_YEAR20_Z.7_ROP_(.*).csv$")
example  = "XR3_DEV_YEAR20_Z.7_ROP_Current1234.csv"

res = exp.match(example)

part = res.groups()[0]
new_name = "XR3_DEV_YEAR20_Z.7_ROP_" + part + "_xml.txt"
```

New name, in this case, would result in :

```
XR3_DEV_YEAR20_Z.7_ROP_Current1234_xml.txt
```

Comment: What does the part refer to?

Comment: @M.Phys - oops. bad copy & paste. Have another look

Comment: I'm thinking there might be an easier way to do this with glob

Comment: AFAIK, glob allows you to find files on disk. What you're looking for here is the ability to create a **new file** name, given an existing one. Isn't this the case?

Comment: In any case, does this solve the problem statement? If so, you may want to mark it as a solution for future generations ...